How to stop ffplay in command line
subprocess.Popen(
            f"\"{self.ffplay_path}\" \"{self.video_path}\"" +
            f" -noborder -left {dx} -top {dy} -x {dvw} -y {dvh} -loop 0" +
            f" -loglevel quiet{' -an' if self.disable_audio else ''}",
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            shell=True)

I launched ffplay in the command line to play the video. But how to pause the playback in the program?
Thank you for your suggestions!
I tried freezing the whole process, but that was just too indecent. And after the process is thawed, the video will flash (when paused, ffplay is playing the 3rd second of the video, after 5 seconds, it will not play the 4th second, but the 8th second after a short stutter).
